# Return promise inside Observable

Tags: angular, firebase, promise, rxjs, angularfire2

I've an Angular app using angularfire2 and I'm using a method which removes some information from a few different tables in firebase.

```
removeTeam(key: string) {
    const dataToRemove = {};
    dataToRemove[`teams/${key}`] = null;

    this.findMembersInTeam(key).subscribe(members => {
      members.forEach(member => {
        dataToRemove[`members/${member}/teams/${key}`] = null;
      });

      this.sdkDB.update(dataToRemove);
    });
  }
```

So what this does, basically is remove /teams/ and also, for every member in the team, remove the team, so remove /members//teams/.

What I do is retrieve the list of members inside a team, and as this is an observable, inside the subscribe I compose the "query" and execute it with `this.sdkDB.update(dataToRemove)`

This last method returns a Promise, and that is what I want to return as the result of the method `removeTeam`, is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: how do you call `removeTeam`? and what do you do with it?

Answer (score 4):

IF `sdkDB` returns an Observable, import `rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap` and use `flatMap` or `mergeMap` (flatMap is just an alias of mergeMap) instead of `subscribe`.

This combines your observable streams.

```
removeTeam(key: string) {
    const dataToRemove = {};
    dataToRemove[`teams/${key}`] = null;

    return this.findMembersInTeam(key)
        .flatMap(members => {
            members.forEach(member => {
                dataToRemove[`members/${member}/teams/${key}`] = null;
            });

            return this.sdkDB.update(dataToRemove);
        })
        .toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: @David In RxJS 5 it doesn't matter and Observables and Promises are handled the same way. Just instead of `flatMap` use `mergeMap` (`flatMap` is just an alias) and subscribe somewhere later in `removeTeam` or return the Observable.

Comment: but I don´t want to return an observable, I want to return a promise.
My interface has an addTeam as well as the removeTeam, and addTeam returns a Promise, so I want to keep things consistent and return a Promise also in removeTeam.

Comment: Check the updated code, you should be able to just chain `toPromise` to it to turn that observable stream into a promise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

// ...

removeTeam(key: string) {
    const dataToRemove = {};
    dataToRemove[`teams/${key}`] = null;
    return this.findMembersInTeam(key)
               .toPromise()
               .then(members => {
                    members.forEach(member => {
                        dataToRemove[`members/${member}/teams/${key}`] = null;
                    });
                    return this.sdkDB.update(dataToRemove);
                });
}
```

Comment: If `sdkDB` returns an Observable, this will not work.

Comment: sdkDB returns a Promise, but this is not working either; I used a .do after the .findMembersInTeam(key) to console.log the data returned and it's working, but the .then() is not being executed

Comment: The `then` part will only work if `findMembersInTeam` returns an Observable.